# How to create a usercontrol which is a popup that behaves like a toast notification popup in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, toast

How to create a usercontrol which is a popup that behaves like a toast notification popup. It slides in from left and can optionally slide out after x second and it should has an implementation for the Tap event which then calls a callback method.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation of such control in the Coding4fun Toolkit: http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Toast%20Prompt&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: i dont want to use toastprompt control from this toolkit as we cant provide customization to it like corner-radius etc. Is their any approach i can follow with user control.

Comment: @Krrish Well, the Coding4fun Toolkit is open-source, so you can retrieve the code of the control and customize it to your heart content